# VBA + print line with quotes to txt file

Tags: vba

my target is to write exactly the following line in to D:\file.txt by VBA

```
 """\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"""
```

.

I write the following VBA code , but after I run this program I get line with only two Quotes in place to get line with six quotes ?

my code:

```
Dim suppname As String

Open "D:\file.txt" For Output As #1

suppname = """"\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz""""

Print #1, suppname
```

.

Example what I got:

```
 "\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"
```

Please advice what I need to fix in my code in order get the following line:

```
 """\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes to escape so;

```
suppname = """""""\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"""""""
```

Comment: just for the sage of completness, another option is to use Chr(34). Like this:
`Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & Chr(34)`